# This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown). It cannot perform a save operation

Tags: core-data, ios7, xcode6, persistence

I am creating an application using Microsoft Azure web service. On clicking logout button I need to clear my local core data base completely and all data will be reloaded after logging in again using the same username and password. To delete core data I am using below method

```
- (void) resetApplicationModel {
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

for (NSPersistentStore *store in delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores) {
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
    NSLog(@"storeURL: %@", storeURL);
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    [storeCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];

    NSLog(@"There are errors: %@", error);
}

delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
context = nil;
delegate.managedObjectModel = nil;
}
```

This is deleting all my data but when I am trying to login again without closing the application it is giving me following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

This is occurring because while deleting data I am setting persistentStoreCoordinator to nil and its instance is being created inside AppDelegate file. Can somebody suggest me any solution for this?

Thanks for help in advance,.

Comment: To check, all you are wanting to achieve is the deletion of all data?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not able to understand you properly. What I am getting is yes I want to achieve data deletion here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of errors.

Regardless, to achieve what you need, try this modified version of your method `resetApplicationModel`...

```
- (void) resetApplicationModel {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//  NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

    for (NSPersistentStore *store in delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores) {
        NSError *error;
        NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
        NSLog(@"storeURL: %@", storeURL);
//      NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;
//      [storeCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];

        NSLog(@"There are errors: %@", error);
    }

//  delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
//  context = nil;
//  delegate.managedObjectModel = nil;
}
```

The intention is you remove the lines of code that are commented out.

Comment: I want to delete my core database completely when user clicks on logout button. By commenting the lines as per your suggestion, it is not deleting my local database. So if possible please how could I improve above code to delete data completely.

Comment: It appears you do not understand Core Data. ["Core Data framework provides generalized and automated solutions to common tasks associated with object life-cycle and object graph management, including persistence."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1) by deleting the persistent store you are deleting the database. There appears to be no reason to set the core data framework to nil.

Comment: I understand this part that deleting the persistent store you are deleting the database. But on the same side just by setting storeURL.path to nil, it is not deleting all entries from my local database.